# My code is not displaying the #firebaseui-auth-container login button - FirebaseUI - Auth

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I added FirebaseUI-web authentication by `<div id="firebaseui-auth-container"></div>` in my html page. The script for #firebaseui-is written in *js/Auth.js* file. My browser is unable to load the script from *js/Auth.j*s. I added `<script type="modules" src="js/Auth.js"></script>` in my html.

Here is my `index.html` code:

```
 <script type="modules" src="js/Auth.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="fp-auth-state-unknown">
  <div class="fp-theatre"><img class="fp-fullpic" alt="Full sized image"></div>
  <section id="page-splash">
    <h3 class="fp-logo">Friendly Pix</h3>
    <div class="fp-caption">The friendliest way to share your pics</div>
    <div class="fp-signed-out-only fp-initially-hidden">
      <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" class="fp-non-eu fp-signed-out-only fp-initially-hidden"></div>
      <a class="fp-non-eu fp-skip" href="/feed">skip sign in</a>
```

The #firebaseui-auth-container is rendered from *js/Auth.j*s file:

```
configureFirebaseUi() {
    // Confgiure and add the FirebaseUI Widget
    let signInFlow = 'popup';
    // For iOS full screen apps we use the redirect auth mode.
    if (('standalone' in window.navigator)
        && window.navigator.standalone) {
      signInFlow = 'redirect';
    }

    // FirebaseUI config.
    this.uiConfig = {
      'signInFlow': signInFlow,
      'signInOptions': [{provider: firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID}],
      'callbacks': {
        'uiShown': function() {
          const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
            const IDPButtons = $('.firebaseui-idp-button');
            const nbIDPButtonDisplayed = IDPButtons.length;
            if (nbIDPButtonDisplayed > 0) {
              clearInterval(intervalId);
              if (!$('#fp-pre-consent').is(':checked')) {
                IDPButtons.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
              }
            }
          }, 1);
        },
      },
    };
    // FirebaseUI
    this.firebaseUi = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
  }

  /**
   * Displays the signed-in user information in the UI or hides it and displays the
   * "Sign-In" button if the user isn't signed-in.
   */
  onAuthStateChanged(user) {
    Router.reloadPage();

    this._waitForAuthPromiseResolver.resolve();
    document.body.classList.remove('fp-auth-state-unknown');
    if (!user) {
      this.userId = null;
      this.signedInUserAvatar.css('background-image', '');
      this.firebaseUi.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', this.uiConfig);
      document.body.classList.remove('fp-signed-in');
      document.body.classList.add('fp-signed-out');
      Auth.disableAdminMode();
    } else {
      this.toggleAdminMode();
      document.body.classList.remove('fp-signed-out');
      document.body.classList.add('fp-signed-in');
      this.userId = user.uid;
      this.signedInUserAvatar.css('background-image',
          `url("${Utils.addSizeToGoogleProfilePic(user.photoURL) || '/images/silhouette.jpg'}")`);
      this.signedInUsername.text(user.displayName || 'Anonymous');
      this.usernameLink.attr('href', `/user/${user.uid}`);
    }
  }
```

> The above script is not loading into the web-browser.
> I tried FirebaseUI-Auth inside the *index.html* page as following:

```
<script type="modules" src="js/Auth.js"></script>
    <!-- *******************************************************************************************
     * Experiment
     ***************************************************************************************** -->
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/6.0.1/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
       // FirebaseUI config.
       firebase.initializeApp()
       var uiConfig = {
         signInOptions: [
           firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
         ],
       };
       // Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
       var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
       // The start method will wait until the DOM is loaded.
       ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', uiConfig);
     </script>
     <!-- *******************************************************************************************
        * Experiment End
        ***************************************************************************************** -->
</head>

<body class="fp-auth-state-unknown">
  <div class="fp-theatre"><img class="fp-fullpic" alt="Full sized image"></div>
  <section id="page-splash">
    <h3 class="fp-logo">Friendly Pix</h3>
    <div class="fp-caption">The friendliest way to share your pics</div>
    <div class="fp-signed-out-only fp-initially-hidden">
      <div id="firebaseui-auth-container" class="fp-non-eu fp-signed-out-only fp-initially-hidden"></div> 
      <a class="fp-non-eu fp-skip" href="/feed">skip sign in</a>
    </div>
```

**The browser is able to load `#firebaseui-auth-container` but unable to display the Sign In button.**
[image]